# Freeing up memory from a non void function

Tags: c, malloc

I am having trouble freeing up memory:

The output I get is this:

```
==11073== 1,000 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 5
==11073==    at 0x4A06A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==11073==    by 0x400B38: userInput (program.c:80)
==11073==    by 0x400DFD: playGame (program.c:150)
==11073==    by 0x4012E9: main (program.c:298)
```

The variables I use are input and answer which are defined outside of main:

```
char *answer;
char *input;
```

The variable 'answer' I use in main like this:

```
line 150    answer = userInput();
```

The function is this:

```
char* userInput()
{
  printf ("> ");

  input = malloc (sizeof(char) * 1000); // THIS is LINE 80
  fgets(input, 1000, stdin);
  //input = realloc(input, strlen(input));

  strtok(input, "\n");

  int i = 0;
  while (i < strlen(input))
  {
    input[i] = tolower(input[i]);
    i++;
  }

  if (strcmp(input, "y") == 0 || strcmp(input, "yep") == 0 || strcmp(input, "yeah") == 0
      || strcmp(input, "absolutely") == 0 || strcmp(input, "correct") == 0)
    input = "yes";

  if (strcmp(input, "n") == 0 || strcmp(input, "nope") == 0)
    input = "no";

  return input;
}
```

Comment: I also never allocate memory in main() for answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You leak the memory here:

```
input = "yes";
```

and here:

```
input = "no";
```

`input` now points to a string literal and the memory it pointed to previously is lost.

Comment: so I should use strcpy?

Comment: @user3143696 Yes if you want to write into memory input is pointing at.